# How do I perform the same customized Ubuntu install on many machines?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, disk-cloning, slipstream

We have eight or so machines with similar (but not necessarily identical) hardware in our development team. We're pair programming, so we want all the machines to be set up in and behave the same way.

This includes every machine having the same operating system software version and patches, the same Ubuntu packages installed, the same 3rd party packages installed in the same filesystem locations, the same Eclipse settings, the same operating system settings (keymaps, printer config, everything.)

How do I best go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's two or three ways to go about doing this, one is the simple dding a single image on every system. The second is to use [remastersys](http://geekconnection.org/remastersys/) or something similar to make a snapshot/installer disk of a baseline setup. The last is to do a file sync with rsync

After install, you could probably consider running your own [repository](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/286) and doing all the updates through that - especially for custom software.

Comment: Sounds like remastersys is the way forward--just to be clear, it will allow me to create a system with all patches and tools installed, then use that as a "prototype" to create an install disk from?

Comment: yup either a installer cd or a livecd identical to the base system, depending on your choices